# Java: Adding to a list of lists

Tags: java, list

Consider the following declaration...

`List<List<Person>> groups;`

I can add to this list by saying `groups.add(new Person(John));`

Is there any way I can add to the inner list rather than the outer one?

Comment: Create a `List`, add a person to it, add it to the other `List`.

Comment: Can I do this without creating another list? I just want to be able to say `groups.` etc etc and add either a new list of people or add more people to an existing list of people.

Comment: You have a `List` of `List`. You need to create a new `List` and do `groups.add(theNewList)`. You can then add to it directly `theNewList.add(new Person())` or by getting a reference from the outer `List` as `groups.get(0).add(new Person())`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Why can't it be done in one statement like `groups.add((new List<Person>).add(new Person("John")))`? What am I missing here?

Comment: @PM The `add` method returns a `boolean`. You could create an anonymous inner class that adds the element. For a one liner `groups.add((new ArrayList<Person>() {{add(new Person("John");}}));` but that's a really bad idea.

Comment: Try `groups.add(new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(new Person("John"))));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<List<Person>> groups;` basically says that each item in the list is a list of `Person`.

This means that in order to add a `Person` to the list, you need to first create a `List` for the element you want to add...

```
List<Person> person = //...
groups.add(person);
```

When you want to add a `Person` to this inner list, you need a reference to it...

```
Person aPerson = //...
groups.get(0).add(aPerson);
```

For example...

**Updated based on comments**

A `Map` might be a better solution for "grouping" like items, for example...

```
Map<String, List<Person>> groups = new HashMap<>();
List<Person> persons = groups.get("family");
if (persons == null) {
    persons = new ArrayList<>(25);
    groups.put("family", persons);
}
persons.add(aPerson);
```

This is a VERY basic example, but help you getting started...A walk through the [Collections trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) might also help

Comment: Kind of off topic here but just need a quick answer. How do i override that get method? Because Im actually storing a list of people and every group of people has a name so ild like to be able to say `groups.get("friends").add("joe");`

Comment: Have you considered using a map of lists rather than a list of lists?  Maps have a get(Object) method that you can use like this.

Comment: @Jules that sounds like what I need. I'll have to read into Maps though, I've never used them.

Comment: @Clay I was wondering about that how you would identify a group

Comment: I have a class `Group`, every group has a name and a list of `People`. So I would like to be able to identify the group by its name that I specify when I construct the group like `Group family = new Group("family");` So maybe like `myMap.get(family.getName()).add(new Person("Joey"));` I think.

Comment: @Clay I added a VERY basic example of using a `Map` which might help

Comment: @MadProgrammer I saw different posts using HashMaps and I have this quick question: What is the difference between `Map<String, List<Person>> groups = new HashMap<>();` and `Map<String, List<Person>> groups = new HashMap<String, List<Person>();`?

Comment: `Map<String, List<Person>> groups` is basically saying, I don't care about the implementation of the `Map`, I just want to use what functionality that the `interface` defines. For example I could have used `Map<String, List<Person>> groups = new TreeMap<>();`. For what I needed, I don't care about the implementation, just the contract, the fact that's it's sorted, to me, is irrelevant (unless you wanted the functionality of a `SortedMap`, then you would have used that instead). Take a look at [this](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/) for some details

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, thanks alot for the help, this Map business is EXACTLY what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

actually you cannot do `groups.add(new Person(John));`

you can do:

```
ArrayList<Person> t = new ArrayList<Person>();
t.add(new Person());
groups.add(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `List<List<Person>> groups;` you cannot do `groups.add(new Person(John));` because `groups` is a `List<List..>` and not `List<Person>`.

What you require is **get-and-add**:

```
List<List<Person>> groups;
//add to group-1
groups = new ArrayList<List<Person>>();
//add a person to group-1
groups.get(0).add(new Person());

//Or alternatively manage groups as Map so IMHO group fetching would be more explicit 
Map<String, List<Person>> groups;
//create new group => students, 
groups = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();//can always use numbers though
groups.put("students", new ArrayList<Person>());

//add to students group
groups.get("students").add(new Person());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a generic double list class to do it for you. Obviously you can extend this if you have certain business logic that will help you figure out internally which list to add to (without giving the index).

```
import java.util.*;

public class DoubleList<T>
{
    private List<List<T>> list;

    public DoubleList()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    }

    public int getOuterCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getInnerCount(int index)
    {
        if (index < list.size())
        {
            return list.get(index).size();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public T get(int index1, int index2)
    {
        return list.get(index1).get(index2);
    }

    public void add(int index, T item)
    {
        while (list.size() <= index)
        {
            list.add(new ArrayList<T>());
        }
        list.get(index).add(item);
    }

    public void add(T item)
    {
        list.add(new ArrayList<T>());
        this.add(list.size() - 1, item);
    }
}
```

**Then you use it like this:**

```
DoubleList<String> mystrs = new DoubleList<String>();

mystrs.add("Volvo");
mystrs.add(0, "Ferrari");

mystrs.add(1, "blue");
mystrs.add(1, "green");

mystrs.add(3, "chocolate");

for (int i = 0; i < mystrs.getOuterCount(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("START");
    for (int j = 0; j < mystrs.getInnerCount(i); j++)
    {
        System.out.println(mystrs.get(i,j));
    }
    System.out.println("FINISH");
}
```